# Remix deployment on digital ocean droplet only times out

Tags: reactjs, nginx, server-side-rendering, digital-ocean, remix.run

I am trying to deploy a remix.run website to a digital ocean droplet. The set up is that I have a remix frontend running on localhost:5000 out of one folder, and then I have a separate nodejs server for database requests running on localhost:8000 in another folder. The issue is that when I visit my url it simply gives a 522 Timout from Cloudflare.

**This is my nginx proxy configuration:**

```
server {
    server_name 143.198.58.178 geopilot.io www.geopilot.io;  # Replace with your domain

    # Set the client body size limit
    client_max_body_size 100M;

    # Enforce the use of secure TLS versions only
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

    # Cloudflare SSL settings
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert.pem;  # Cloudflare Origin Certificate
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/key.pem;  # Cloudflare Private Key
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/cloudflare.crt;  # Cloudflare CA certificate for Origin Pull
    ssl_verify_client on;  # Enable verification of Cloudflare Origin Pulls


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;  # Assuming your app runs on port 5000
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
   location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;  # Assuming your app runs on port 5000
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
server {
    if ($host = www.geopilot.io) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }  # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = geopilot.io) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }  # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name geopilot.io www.geopilot.io;
    return 404;  # managed by Certbot
}
```

**I am using the express remix option, this is the express server**

```
import * as fs from "node:fs";
import * as path from "node:path";
import * as url from "node:url";

import { createRequestHandler } from "@remix-run/express";
import { broadcastDevReady, installGlobals } from "@remix-run/node";
import compression from "compression";
import express from "express";
import morgan from "morgan";
import sourceMapSupport from "source-map-support";

sourceMapSupport.install({
  retrieveSourceMap: function (source) {
    const match = source.startsWith("file://");
    if (match) {
      const filePath = url.fileURLToPath(source);
      const sourceMapPath = `${filePath}.map`;
      if (fs.existsSync(sourceMapPath)) {
        return {
          url: source,
          map: fs.readFileSync(sourceMapPath, "utf8"),
        };
      }
    }
    return null;
  },
});
installGlobals();

/** @typedef {import('@remix-run/node').ServerBuild} ServerBuild */

const BUILD_PATH = path.resolve("build/index.js");
const VERSION_PATH = path.resolve("build/version.txt");

const initialBuild = await reimportServer();
const remixHandler =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
    ? await createDevRequestHandler(initialBuild)
    : createRequestHandler({
      build: initialBuild,
      mode: initialBuild.mode,
    });

const app = express();

app.use(compression());

// http://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-security.html#at-a-minimum-disable-x-powered-by-header
app.disable("x-powered-by");

// Remix fingerprints its assets so we can cache forever.
app.use(
  "/build",
  express.static("public/build", { immutable: true, maxAge: "1y" })
);

// Everything else (like favicon.ico) is cached for an hour. You may want to be
// more aggressive with this caching.
app.use(express.static("public", { maxAge: "1h" }));

app.use(morgan("tiny"));

app.all("*", remixHandler);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, async () => {
  console.log(`Express server listening at http://localhost:${port}`);

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
    broadcastDevReady(initialBuild);
  }
});

/**
 * @returns {Promise<ServerBuild>}
 */
async function reimportServer() {
  const stat = fs.statSync(BUILD_PATH);

  // convert build path to URL for Windows compatibility with dynamic `import`
  const BUILD_URL = url.pathToFileURL(BUILD_PATH).href;

  // use a timestamp query parameter to bust the import cache
  return import(BUILD_URL + "?t=" + stat.mtimeMs);
}

/**
 * @param {ServerBuild} initialBuild
 * @returns {Promise<import('@remix-run/express').RequestHandler>}
 */
async function createDevRequestHandler(initialBuild) {
  let build = initialBuild;
  async function handleServerUpdate() {
    // 1. re-import the server build
    build = await reimportServer();
    // 2. tell Remix that this app server is now up-to-date and ready
    broadcastDevReady(build);
  }
  const chokidar = await import("chokidar");
  chokidar
    .watch(VERSION_PATH, { ignoreInitial: true })
    .on("add", handleServerUpdate)
    .on("change", handleServerUpdate);

  // wrap request handler to make sure its recreated with the latest build for every request
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      return createRequestHandler({
        build,
        mode: "development",
      })(req, res, next);
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  };
}
```

**Finally the package.json for remix**

```
{
  "name": "my-remix-app",
  "private": true,
  "sideEffects": false,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "remix build",
    "dev": "remix dev -c \"node remixServer/server.mjs\"",
    "lint": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore --cache --cache-location ./node_modules/.cache/eslint .",
    "start": "pm2 start remixServer/server.mjs --name 'RemixFrontend'",
    "stop": "pm2 stop RemixFrontend",
    "restart": "pm2 restart RemixFrontend",
    "typecheck": "tsc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@loadable/component": "^5.16.2",
    "@mapbox/mapbox-sdk": "^0.15.3",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.1",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.157",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.1",
    "@remix-run/css-bundle": "^2.4.0",
    "@remix-run/express": "^2.4.1",
    "@remix-run/node": "^2.4.0",
    "@remix-run/react": "^2.4.0",
    "@remix-run/serve": "^2.4.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "browser-image-compression": "^2.0.2",
    "cloudinary": "^1.41.1",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-http-proxy": "^2.0.0",
    "express-mongo-sanitize": "^2.2.0",
    "express-promise-router": "^4.1.1",
    "express-validator": "^7.0.1",
    "firebase": "^10.7.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^12.0.0",
    "formik": "^2.4.5",
    "isbot": "^3.6.8",
    "mapbox-gl": "^3.0.1",
    "mongoose": "^8.0.3",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "mui-tel-input": "^5.0.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "multer-storage-cloudinary": "^4.0.0",
    "node-cron": "^3.0.3",
    "p-min-delay": "^4.0.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-country-flag": "^3.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.12.0",
    "react-map-gl": "^7.1.7",
    "react-mapbox-autocomplete": "^0.2.3",
    "react-phone-input-2": "^2.15.1",
    "react-phone-number-input": "^3.3.9",
    "react-query": "^3.39.3",
    "sanitize-html": "^2.11.0",
    "yup": "^1.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@remix-run/dev": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/loadable__component": "^5.13.8",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.7.4",
    "eslint": "^8.38.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.28.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.0.0"
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly greatly appreciated, it's important to note that there are zero errors I can find anywhere other than the 522

I have tried various nginx configs, I have tried reconfiguring my server, I have tried moving around my everything into different folders and setups.